# What is the correct way to defer loading MySQL results in an HTML table?

Tags: php, mysql

I am loading MySQL data into a paginated html table using the following code:

```
<table data-paginate="true">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT column_1, column_2, column_3 FROM table";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<tr><td>" . $row["column_1"] . "</td><td>" . $row["column_2"] . "</td><td>" . $row["column_3"] . "</td></tr>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
        $conn->close();
    ?> 
</tbody>
</table>
```

This approach isn't very practical when it comes to handling large amounts of data. What is the correct way to defer the loading of my MySQL query until the user clicks onto the next page of the table?

Comment: I don't see pagination in your code. Do you want it this way? I mean the same output?

Comment: you just need to use correct format?

Answer (score 0):

You dont defer, i.e store the result somewhere and then reuse it.

You amend your query to select the right 10 rows for example on each iteration round your pagination like

First page:

```
SELECT column_1, column_2, column_3 FROM table LIMIT 0,10
```

Second page:

```
SELECT column_1, column_2, column_3 FROM table LIMIT 9,10
```

Third page:

```
SELECT column_1, column_2, column_3 FROM table LIMIT 19,10
```

All you then need is to store `$rows_per_page` and `$current_page` and you can calulate the LIMIT values from that each time the form sends a page_number, or a page_plus_1 or a page_minus_1, to your script.

Answer (score 0):

You need pagination here.
Pagination itself has 2 types

```
1) server side 
              On clicking the next button, it re-queries and brings the data

2) client side
             Loads whole of the data in one go but uses jquery to show it in divisions.
```

Don't re-invent the wheel, use existing apis like https://www.datatables.net/.
It has both of them and it support the export features too.